# Can I show file copy progress using FileInfo.CopyTo() in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, copy, fileinfo

I've created a copy utility in c# (.NET 2.0 Framework) that copies files, directories and recursive sub directories etc. The program has a GUI that shows the current file being copied, the current file number (sequence), the total number of files to be copied and the percentage completed for the copy operations. There is also a progress bar, that is based on current file / total files.

My problem is related to copying large files. I've been unable to find a way to indicate the total copy progress of a large file (using my current class structure that utilitzes FileInfo.CopyTo method). As a workaround I've separated the file copy operations and GUI display to their own threads and set up a visual cue to show that work is being done. At least the user is aware that the program isn't frozen and is still copying files.

It would be nicer to be able to show the progress based on the total number of bytes or have some type of event that fires from the FileInfo.CopyTo method that indicates the total number of bytes copied from the current file.

I'm aware of the FileInfo.Length property, so I'm sure there is a way MacGuyver my own event that is based on this and have a handler on the GUI side of things reading the updates (maybe based on checking the FileInfo.Length property of the destination object using some type of timer?).

Does anyone know of a way to do this that I'm overlooking. If I can avoid it, I'd rather not rewrite my class to copy bytes through a stream and track it that way (though I'm thinking I might be stuck with going that route).

PS - I'm stuck with the .NET 2.0 framework for now, so any solution that requires features available in >= 3.0 only are not an option for me.

PPS - I'm open to solutions in any .NET language variety, not only c#.

Comment: any full sample source code ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The FileInfo.CopyTo is basically a wrapper around the Win32 API call "CopyFile" in the kernel32.dll. This method does not support progress callback.

However, the CopyFileEx method does, and you can write your own .NET wrapper around it in a few minutes, like it is described here:
[http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200428185128/http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx)

Comment: Thanks Gaspar. This option looks like one possible way to tackle the issue. I'll look into it a little more.

Comment: For what its worth I have successfully used this approach.  In fact I'm pretty sure I literally copied that very code from pinvoke.net.  agentidle you could make a nice little class to wrap it instead of dealing with all the parameters.

Answer (score 28):

I also used the implementation provided in the [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/187842/73025). However I then created a wrapper to provide a nicer™ API to use from .NET.

**Usage:**

```
XCopy.Copy(networkFile.FullPath, temporaryFilename, true, true, (o, pce) => 
{
    worker.ReportProgress(pce.ProgressPercentage, networkFile);
});
```

**Implementation**

```
/// <summary>
/// PInvoke wrapper for CopyEx
/// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx
/// </summary>
public class XCopy
{
    public static void Copy(string source, string destination, bool overwrite, bool nobuffering)
    {
         new XCopy().CopyInternal(source, destination, overwrite, nobuffering, null);            
    }

    public static void Copy(string source, string destination, bool overwrite, bool nobuffering, EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> handler)
    {            
         new XCopy().CopyInternal(source, destination, overwrite, nobuffering, handler);            
    }

    private event EventHandler Completed;
    private event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    private int IsCancelled;
    private int FilePercentCompleted;
    private string Source;
    private string Destination;        

    private XCopy()
    {
        IsCancelled = 0;
    }

    private void CopyInternal(string source, string destination, bool overwrite, bool nobuffering, EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> handler)
    {
        try
        {
            CopyFileFlags copyFileFlags = CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE;
            if (!overwrite)
                copyFileFlags |= CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS;

            if (nobuffering)
                copyFileFlags |= CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING;

            Source = source;
            Destination = destination;

            if (handler != null)
                ProgressChanged += handler;

            bool result = CopyFileEx(Source, Destination, new CopyProgressRoutine(CopyProgressHandler), IntPtr.Zero, ref IsCancelled, copyFileFlags);
            if (!result)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (handler != null)
                ProgressChanged -= handler;

            throw;
        }
    }

    private void OnProgressChanged(double percent)
    {
        // only raise an event when progress has changed
        if ((int)percent > FilePercentCompleted)
        {
            FilePercentCompleted = (int)percent;

            var handler = ProgressChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs((int)FilePercentCompleted, null));
        }
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        var handler = Completed;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #region PInvoke

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref Int32 pbCancel, CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

    private delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(long TotalFileSize, long TotalBytesTransferred, long StreamSize, long StreamBytesTransferred, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
                                                    IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData);

    private enum CopyProgressResult : uint
    {
        PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
        PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
        PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
        PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
    }

    private enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
    {
        CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
        CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum CopyFileFlags : uint
    {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING = 0x00001000,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
        COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
        COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008
    }

    private CopyProgressResult CopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long streamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber,
                                                   CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
    {
        if (reason == CopyProgressCallbackReason.CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED)
            OnProgressChanged((transferred / (double)total) * 100.0);

        if (transferred >= total)
            OnCompleted();

        return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: It is nice. I actually did not end up using it as I found x100 better performance using the `WebClient` to download the file async.

Comment: @Dennis see my post here if you have some time (using this code) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354610/copyfileex-the-parameter-is-invalid-error

Comment: There seems to be some parts of this program missing. How can i tie the progress to a progressbar???

Comment: Even though this is an old post: Nice solution, but as-is not thread safe. If this is called from multiple threads, all feedback ends up getting sent to every active listener. Maybe I'm posting an improvement later.

Comment: Uh, seems I was wrong, sorry. The event is not kept statically and the callback happens on an instance. Everything fine.

Comment: @PMF Good to know that it is thread-safe as I thought that I did handle it. I* haven't reviewed this solution for a long time. If I did revisit, I would make it `async`. **NB** that better performance is possible with using a web client.

Comment: @Dennis how come WebClient is 100 times better than this PInvoke for file copying purposes?

Comment: @Ehouarn Are you using the code verbatim as posted above?

CopyFileFlags copyFileFlags = CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE;

The COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE flag degrades performance dramatically. 

If you are not using COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE, can you elaborate on WebClient? I'm looking for a solution to this myself.

I do wish there was a more clear explanation of when to use COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING.

Comment: @KerryPerret Almost certainly WebClient was measured wrong. It has DownloadFileAsync, which returns before the operation is finished. You can call it to download 10 Terabytes of data and it will return in 10 milliseconds. Benchmarking is easy to get wrong. To measure more correctly, use DownloadFile() or DownloadFileTaskAsync.Wait(). Both block, but that's fine for benchmarking.

Comment: Oh boy need to get my head around, it's been two years since I posted my comment ^^

Comment: Same, thinking back 8yrs ago I think x100 was an "unmeasured exaggeration" because I was naive developer and didn't know how to benchmark things. :)

Answer (score 13):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I made a wrapper for `CopyFileEx` that returns a `Task` and accepts a `CancellationToken` and `IProgress<double>`. Unfortunately it won't work in the .NET 2.0 framework, but for anyone using 4.5, this allows you to use the `await` keyword.

```
public static class FileEx
{
    public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
    {
        return CopyAsync(sourceFileName, destFileName, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return CopyAsync(sourceFileName, destFileName, token, null);
    }

    public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, IProgress<double> progress)
    {
        return CopyAsync(sourceFileName, destFileName, CancellationToken.None, progress);
    }

    public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, CancellationToken token, IProgress<double> progress)
    {
        int pbCancel = 0;
        CopyProgressRoutine copyProgressHandler;
        if (progress != null)
        {
            copyProgressHandler = (total, transferred, streamSize, streamByteTrans, dwStreamNumber, reason, hSourceFile, hDestinationFile, lpData) =>
            {
                progress.Report((double)transferred / total * 100);
                return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
            };
        }
        else
        {
            copyProgressHandler = EmptyCopyProgressHandler;
        }
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        var ctr = token.Register(() => pbCancel = 1);
        var copyTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                CopyFileEx(sourceFileName, destFileName, copyProgressHandler, IntPtr.Zero, ref pbCancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            finally
            {
                ctr.Dispose();
            }
        }, token);
        return copyTask;
    }

    private static CopyProgressResult EmptyCopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long streamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
    {
        return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
    }

    #region DLL Import

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
       CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref Int32 pbCancel,
       CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

    delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
        long totalFileSize,
        long totalBytesTransferred,
        long streamSize,
        long streamBytesTransferred,
        uint dwStreamNumber,
        CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
        IntPtr hSourceFile,
        IntPtr hDestinationFile,
        IntPtr lpData);

    enum CopyProgressResult : uint
    {
        PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
        PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
        PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
        PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
    }

    enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
    {
        CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
        CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
    }

    [Flags]
    enum CopyFileFlags : uint
    {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
        COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
        COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I asked the question 6 years ago, so an updated answer that is relevant for the times is certainly welcome.

Answer (score 9):

For the love of God do not implement your own file copy using streams!  The Win32 CopyFile API call that Gaspar mentioned is able to take advantage of e.g. DMA, whereas I'd bet dollars to doughnuts that the code Will wrote would not be "smart" enough to do that.

CopyFileEx will treat you right, or you could implement a BackgroundWorker that watches the growing size of the target file and updates a progress bar using that information.  The latter method saves you a PInvoke, but the former is probably a bit cleaner in the long run.

Comment: Watching the target file using by using a FileInfo object and checking the length is another option I have considered. I agree though that using the CopyFileEx approach is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I'm very happy this answer exists. It should be a sticky note below most questions regarding file copying. Most people don't know that you can e.g. copy from disk to network directly without involving the CPU at all.

Answer (score 5):

For these sorts of things I have fallen back to Shell32 (or is it ShellUI?  I don't know anymore).  This gives you a native Windows dialog that users are used to seeing for copying operations.  I guess it would replace your already existing dialog so it may not be the right answer for you, but it is useful to remember for those "in a pinch" scenarios.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(
    srcPath, 
    dstPath, 
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,    
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.ThrowException
);
```

Yes, you must reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.  I've grown to [love](http://www.deploymentzone.com/2008/08/11/microsoftvisualbasic/) this assembly.

Comment: The only reason I didn't take this route is that I needed to ensure the user couldn't cancel the copy operation.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Gasper and @Dennis for pointing out CopyFileEx method. 
I have extended dennis answer with abort copy

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Type indicates how the copy gets completed.
    /// </summary>
    internal enum CopyCompletedType
    {
        Succeeded,
        Aborted,
        Exception
    }

/// <summary>
/// Event arguments for file copy 
/// </summary>
internal class FileCopyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">type of the copy completed type enum</param>
    /// <param name="exception">exception if any</param>
    public FileCopyEventArgs(CopyCompletedType type, Exception exception)
    {
        Type = type;
        Exception = exception;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Type of the copy completed type
    /// </summary>
    public CopyCompletedType Type
    {
        get;
        private set;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exception if any happend during copy.
    /// </summary>
    public Exception Exception
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// PInvoke wrapper for CopyEx
/// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx
/// </summary>
internal class XCopy
{

    private int IsCancelled;
    private int FilePercentCompleted;

    public XCopy()
    {
        IsCancelled = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the file asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">the source path</param>
    /// <param name="destination">the destination path</param>
    /// <param name="nobuffering">Bufferig status</param>
    /// <param name="handler">Event handler to do file copy.</param>
    public void CopyAsync(string source, string destination, bool nobuffering)
    {
        try
        {
            //since we needed an async copy ..
            Action action = new Action(
                () => CopyInternal(source, destination, nobuffering)
                    );
            Task task = new Task(action);
            task.Start();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            //handle the inner exception since exception thrown from task are wrapped in
            //aggreate exception.
            OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType.Exception, ex.InnerException);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType.Exception, ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event which will notify the subscribers if the copy gets completed
    /// There are three scenarios in which completed event will be thrown when
    /// 1.Copy succeeded
    /// 2.Copy aborted.
    /// 3.Any exception occured.
    /// These information can be obtained from the Event args.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<FileCopyEventArgs> Completed;
    /// <summary>
    /// Event which will notify the subscribers if there is any progress change while copying.
    /// This will indicate the progress percentage in its event args.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Aborts the copy asynchronously and throws Completed event when done.
    /// User may not want to wait for completed event in case of Abort since 
    /// the event will tell that copy has been aborted.
    /// </summary>
    public void AbortCopyAsync()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Aborting the copy");
        //setting this will cancel an operation since we pass the
        //reference to copyfileex and it will periodically check for this.
        //otherwise also We can check for iscancelled on onprogresschanged and return 
        //Progress_cancelled .
        IsCancelled = 1;

        Action completedEvent = new Action(() =>
            {
                //wait for some time because we ll not know when IsCancelled is set , at what time windows stops copying.
                //so after sometime this may become valid .
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                //do we need to wait for some time and send completed event.
                OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType.Aborted);
                //reset the value , otherwise if we try to copy again since value is 1 , 
                //it thinks that its aborted and wont allow to copy.
                IsCancelled = 0;
            });

        Task completedTask = new Task(completedEvent);
        completedTask.Start();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the file using asynchronos task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">the source path</param>
    /// <param name="destination">the destination path</param>
    /// <param name="nobuffering">Buffering status</param>
    /// <param name="handler">Delegate to handle Progress changed</param>
    private void CopyInternal(string source, string destination, bool nobuffering)
    {
        CopyFileFlags copyFileFlags = CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE;

        if (nobuffering)
        {
            copyFileFlags |= CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING;
        }

        try
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("File copy started with Source: " + source + " and destination: " + destination);
            //call win32 api.
            bool result = CopyFileEx(source, destination, new CopyProgressRoutine(CopyProgressHandler), IntPtr.Zero, ref IsCancelled, copyFileFlags);
            if (!result)
            {
                //when ever we get the result as false it means some error occured so get the last win 32 error.
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //the mesage will contain the requested operation was aborted when the file copy
            //was cancelled. so we explicitly check for that and do a graceful exit
            if (ex.Message.Contains("aborted"))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Copy aborted.");
            }
            else
            {
                OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType.Exception, ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnProgressChanged(double percent)
    {
        // only raise an event when progress has changed
        if ((int)percent > FilePercentCompleted)
        {
            FilePercentCompleted = (int)percent;

            var handler = ProgressChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs((int)FilePercentCompleted, null));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType type, Exception exception = null)
    {
        var handler = Completed;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new FileCopyEventArgs(type, exception));
        }
    }

    #region PInvoke

    /// <summary>
    /// Delegate which will be called by Win32 API for progress change
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="total">the total size</param>
    /// <param name="transferred">the transferrred size</param>
    /// <param name="streamSize">size of the stream</param>
    /// <param name="streamByteTrans"></param>
    /// <param name="dwStreamNumber">stream number</param>
    /// <param name="reason">reason for callback</param>
    /// <param name="hSourceFile">the source file handle</param>
    /// <param name="hDestinationFile">the destination file handle</param>
    /// <param name="lpData">data passed by users</param>
    /// <returns>indicating whether to continue or do somthing else.</returns>
    private CopyProgressResult CopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long streamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber,
                                                   CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
    {
        //when a chunk is finished call the progress changed.
        if (reason == CopyProgressCallbackReason.CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED)
        {
            OnProgressChanged((transferred / (double)total) * 100.0);
        }

        //transfer completed
        if (transferred >= total)
        {
            if (CloseHandle(hDestinationFile))
            {
                OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType.Succeeded, null);
            }
            else
            {
                OnCompleted(CopyCompletedType.Exception,
                    new System.IO.IOException("Unable to close the file handle"));
            }
        }

        return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref Int32 pbCancel, CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

    private delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(long TotalFileSize, long TotalBytesTransferred, long StreamSize, long StreamBytesTransferred, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
                                                    IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData);

    private enum CopyProgressResult : uint
    {
        PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
        PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
        PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
        PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
    }

    private enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
    {
        CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
        CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum CopyFileFlags : uint
    {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING = 0x00001000,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
        COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
        COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008
    }

    #endregion

}
```

The clients can create an object of XCopy class and call copy/abort method .

Comment: CloseHandle(hDestinationFile) should not be performed as the OS will also attempt to close the handle and return an exception when that fails.   Should perform the OnCompleted(CopyCompleteType.Succeeded... by CopyInternal()

Answer (score 2):

If someone still stumbles into this problem (10 years later!) as I did, I have created a wrapper around CopyFileEx and MoveFileWithProgress functions (as some of the answers here) with some extra, useful functionality (such as async, access rights check, formatting of bytes, copying directories...)

Check it here - 
[GitHub](https://github.com/martinchrzan/FileTransferManager) and
[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileTransferManager/)