# How to copy a file with the ability to cancel the copy?

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

I’m trying to have the *program* be able to cancel the copy. Therefore I can’t use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile`.

There are some wrappers for `CopyFileEx` on the web such as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163851.aspx). However, I rather not use something I don’t understand, not wanting any unexpected results (or bugs). Is there a managed way to do this? Or perhaps a wrapper by MS (in something like Windows API CodePack)?

Comment: However you do it, you're probably going to want to copy to a temp file, then move the temp file to the right place once the copy's done.  That way you won't trash the (potentially existing) destination file when the copy's canceled.

Comment: Copying a file *correctly* is ridiculously difficult.  Use Toub's code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the file in small chunks and write it out to the destination. Periodically check whether you've been asked to cancel and if you detect that, stop writing and close the files.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187768/can-i-show-file-copy-progress-using-fileinfo-copyto-in-net) in Coderer’s answer that, for example, my code wouldn’t take advantage of DMA.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried copying the stream in chunks and each time you check the chunk check if a cancel was set, or a cancellation token was registered?

For example you could do something like:

```
void CopyStream(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        if(cancelled){
           // cleanup

           return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please take a look here if you can see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537214/copy-a-file-in-little-chunks