# How can I know the bytes current being copied during copying large file in .net?

Tags: .net, winapi

How can I know the bytes current being copied during copying large file in .net?

I used to `File.Copy`  method for copying file.

The problem is I can't know the current state  during copying file.

Is there anyway that I can check how much the file is being copied? or get a return value?

If not, do I have to make my own method with `Filestream` or something?

Sorry about my poor English & thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187768/can-i-show-file-copy-progress-using-fileinfo-copyto-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would leave copying to the OS rather than rolling out your own, you can use the [`CopyFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API which implements a progress callback ([pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFileEx)).

Comment: Or possibly even SHFileOperation

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is I can't know the current state during copying file.

Just use the following method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364957(v=vs.85).aspx

> Is there anyway that I can check how much the file is being copied? or
>   get a return value?

Check the size on the file being created in the new location using a similar method as above.

> If not, do I have to make my own method with Filestream or something?

You really should avoid doing something that operating system does.