# Copy files with progress

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting the most efficient way to copy a file with a progress bar updating the copy percentage.

This is the standard copy code I am using:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(source,target)
```

This is very fast and efficient. However, I cannot report the copy percentage.
I have tried many functions that read and save a file by opening up the filestream and then looping while reading/writing the data. This enables me to report the progress.

Here are the functions that I am using:

```
    Public Sub SaveBinaryFile(strFilename As String, bytesToWrite() As Byte)
    Dim position As Integer = 0
    Dim BufferSize As Integer = 4096
    'frmMain.tsProgressBar.Value = 0

    Using fsNew As FileStream = New FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Do
            Dim intToCopy As Integer = Math.Min(BufferSize, bytesToWrite.Length - position)
            Dim buffer(intToCopy - 1) As Byte
            Array.Copy(bytesToWrite, position, buffer, 0, intToCopy)
            fsNew.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            'frmMain.tsProgressBar.Value = ((position / bytesToWrite.Length) * 100)
            'frmMain.tsProgressBar.Refresh()
            Application.DoEvents()
            position += intToCopy
        Loop While position < bytesToWrite.Length
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function ReadBinaryFile(strFilename As String) As Byte()
    Dim position As Integer = 0
    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 4096
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    'frmMain.tsProgressBar.Value = 0

    Using fsOpen As FileStream = New FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open)
        ReDim bytes((fsOpen.Length) - 1)
        Do
            If (position + bufferSize) > fsOpen.Length Then
                fsOpen.Read(bytes, position, fsOpen.Length - position)
                Exit Do
            Else
                fsOpen.Read(bytes, position, bufferSize)
            End If
            'frmMain.tsProgressBar.Value = ((position / fsOpen.Length) * 100)
            'frmMain.tsProgressBar.Refresh()
            Application.DoEvents()
            position += bufferSize
        Loop
    End Using

    Return bytes

End Function
```

The problem is that is a lot slower than using the straight copy code.

What is the best/efficient way to copy a file showing the copy progress?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I show file copy progress using FileInfo.CopyTo() in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187768/can-i-show-file-copy-progress-using-fileinfo-copyto-in-net)

Comment: I have tried this: My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFileName, destinationFilename, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs) but with no luck. I also added "Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO"

Answer (score 2):

There is a variant of `System.IO.File` that provides user feedback; it's called `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem`. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165446.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\[Copy From]", "C:\[Copy To]", _
                        FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
' this requires the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, which is referenced from Visual Basic .NET
' projects by default, but needs to be added to C# projects manually
```

OR :

```
Dim CF As New IO.FileStream("C:\[Copy From]", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim CT As New IO.FileStream("C:\[Copy To]", IO.FileMode.Create)
Dim len As Long = CF.Length - 1
Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
Dim byteCFead As Integer
While CF.Position < len
    byteCFead = (CF.Read(buffer, 0, 1024))
    CT.Write(buffer, 0, byteCFead)
    ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(CF.Position / len * 100)
    Application.DoEvents()
End While
CT.Flush()
CT.Close()
CF.Close()
```

OR : Using WebClient

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If Not OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then Return
If Not FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then Return
Button1.Enabled = False
WebClient1.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(OpenFileDialog1.FileName), Path.Combine(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileName))
End Sub

Private Sub WebClient1_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebClient1.DownloadProgressChanged
ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub WebClient1_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebClient1.DownloadFileCompleted
Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should consider improving your solution by including code comments and elaborating on *why* and *how* your code works.

Comment: There is no System.IO.File.Copy which takes a UIOption parameter.

Comment: @Daniel sorry bro, i have been working alone for 8 years 

Comment: @max.weller I'm sure it does, I have used it a couple of times, On windows 8.1 to be exact.

Comment: @Fa3o - The one which works is in the VisualBasic space -- Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFileName, destinationFileName, UIOption.AllDialogs).  That's probably what you were remembering...  I think max was right.  It appears that there is no System.IO.File.Copy which takes a UIOption parameter.  So, you're both sorta right  :-)

Answer (score 0):

hmm Try this function

```
 Dim D As Integer
Function CopyFileWithProgress(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Destination As String) As Integer
    Try

        Dim SourceF As New IO.FileStream(TextBox1.Text, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim DestinationF As New IO.FileStream(TextBox2.Text & "\" & TextBox3.Text & ".ps4game", IO.FileMode.Create)
        Dim len As Long = SourceF.Length - 1
        Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
        Dim byteCFead As Integer
        While SourceF.Position < len
            byteCFead = (SourceF.Read(buffer, 0, 1024))
            DestinationF.Write(buffer, 0, byteCFead)
            D = CInt(SourceF.Position / len * 100)
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        DestinationF.Flush()
        DestinationF.Close()
        SourceF.Close()
        Return D
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

it will work