# FTP download chunk copy

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, copy

A while back I asked a question revolving around how to copy a file in chunks from one location to another: [CopyFileEx "The parameter is invalid" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354610/copyfileex-the-parameter-is-invalid-error)

I received the following code which was quite helpful.

```
    static void chunkCopyFile(string source, string destination, int bytesPerChunk)
    {
        uint bytesRead = 0;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs)) {
                using (FileStream fsDest = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create)) {
                    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsDest);
                    byte[] buffer;

                    for (int i = 0; i < fs.Length; i += bytesPerChunk) {
                        buffer = br.ReadBytes(bytesPerChunk);
                        bw.Write(buffer);
                        bytesRead += Convert.ToUInt32(bytesPerChunk);
                        updateProgress(bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I now need to convert this code to use FTP instead. I tried the obvious of just passing the FTP path to the filestream but it gave me an error saying "unsupported".

I already managed to get the file length, I'm just not sure how I can split the download into chunks. Any help is appreciated as always!

Code so far(not much)

```
static void chunkCopyFTPFile(string destination, int bytesPerChunk)
    {
        uint bytesRead = 0;

        fWR = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + FTP_SERVER_NAME + "/test.txt");
        fWR.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        fWR.UseBinary = true;

        fWR.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTP_SERVER_USERNAME, FTP_SERVER_PASSWORD);

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)fWR.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        sR.ReadToEnd();

        sR.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Final code (working):

```
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            using (BinaryReader bR = new BinaryReader(responseStream)) {
                using (FileStream fsDest = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create)) {
                    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsDest);
                    int readCount;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesPerChunk];

                    readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesPerChunk);
                    bytesRead += Convert.ToUInt32(readCount);
                    updateProgress(bytesRead);

                    while (readCount > 0) {
                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                        readCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesPerChunk);
                        bytesRead += Convert.ToUInt32(readCount);
                        updateProgress(bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking for [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class?

Comment: @Reniuz I'm already using it! I'm just not sure of how to use it to download a file in chunks rather than all at once...

Comment: Cant see where you using it. I see just 2 file streams.

Comment: @Reniuz zorry, I mean I'm using it in other parts of the application. I'm aware I need to use it for downloading the file, I'm just not sure how to split it up. I'll edit in the code I do have, even though it isn't much.

Comment: Ok. Almost everything stays same as current your code -all you need is to get stream to file via ftp. Instead of destination FileStream use FtpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711) is an example. Ill try to create pseudo code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what you could try. This code is not tested. So if it contains errors and you get it work please edit answer or point me to mistakes.

```
static void chunkCopyFile(string source, string destination, int bytesPerChunk)
{
    uint bytesRead = 0;
    //Instead of this:
    //using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {

    //...some necessary stuff...
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    //Use this:
    using(Stream fs = response.GetResponseStream()){

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs)) {
            using (FileStream fsDest = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create)) {
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsDest);
                long cl = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                   bw.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                   readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   updateProgress(readCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17202/Simple-FTP-demo-application-using-C-Net-2-0 (Download method code)

Comment: The line "buffer = br.ReadBytes(bytesPerChunk) throws an exception: 
"This stream does not support seek operations."

Comment: I updated answer. I also added reference where you could see all download code. Sorry I cant test code right now :(

Comment: Got it working based on what you gave, final code is in the question! Thanks :)

Comment: Good to hear that. P.s. just a note...you dont need convert readCount to int `bytesRead += Convert.ToUInt32(readCount);` just use `bytesRead += readCount;`

Comment: I'm converting it to a Uint, so yes, I need to convert :)