# Can i achieve progress bar with copying files between client and server using CopyTo

Tags: c#, sockets, file-io, filestream, networkstream

I coded a file sharing app using `FileStream.CopyTo` copying files for me.To add Progress bar facility in it,I found a dozen of links googling and saying to use `CopyFileEx` for Progress bar using CallBack method .After a detailed reading of MSDN docs.I found another option `WebClient` for the same purpose and confused me rather more.I then skimmed through [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=854) where the author doesn't talk about `Stream.CopyTo` but advocating `CopyFileEx` too.

I am already done with coding using `CopyTo` method.For progress bar will it provide me facility and how?

PS. I searched a lot but none of link showed me how to implement it using `CopyTo`.

Here's my code For Client-side:

```
         NetworkStream netstream = clientSocket.GetStream();


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                TransmitFileName(netstream, Path.GetFileName(path));

              //  MessageBox.Show("Starting Data Transfer");

                int data_len = (int)fs.Length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int totalbytes = 0;
                while (totalbytes < data_len)
                {

                    var bytesread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (totalbytes == data_len) { break; }
                    try
                    {
                        netstream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
                        totalbytes += bytesread;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                    }
                 }

               string suff_tb= SizeSuffix(totalbytes);

                MessageBox.Show("Total Bytes Receieved" + suff_tb);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data transfer completed");
                fs.Close();
                netstream.Close();

            }

        }
```

Server-side:

```
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileloc));
            //copy data from client machine to local drive

            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileloc, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    netStream.CopyTo(fs);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exx.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                netStream.Close();
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileloc);
                long siz = fi.Length;
                MessageBox.Show("File Size is" + SizeSuffix(siz));


            }
```

Comment: The answer is No. It can be Yes if you have to copy multiple files (then you have total number of files and copying them in cycle gives you progress). Problem is what `CopyTo` doesn't gives you any way to determine progress. It is started and when its finished - file is 100% copied. You can use *progressless indicator* (animated gif of something rotating, jumping, whatever). Or you have to use other ways. WinAPI `CopyFileEx` has `CopyProgressRoutine` callback, in which you **can** estimate progress of currently copied single file.

Comment: Progressless indicator..........will u elaborate?

Comment: Have u a working example of `CopyFileEx` with Progress bar...i need  it @Sinatr

Comment: Couldn't i achieve something(other than CopyFileEx)like suggested here?-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354610/copyfileex-the-parameter-is-invalid-error

Comment: [Progressless](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r6tWv.gif) indicator. [CopyFileEx example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36647/How-to-copy-files-in-C-with-a-customizable-progres).