# get transfer speed from FileInfo.CopyTo in C#

Tags: c#, transfer

i need to get transfer speed in FileInfo.CopyTo via c#.
But my search for a suitable alternative not hove good result.
can you help me?

Comment: Would this code be of any use to you? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8e03fe68-e6d5-42bf-8b70-225c58b8a177. Focus on the reply of SharpAspirant. Especially the `int speed = Convert.ToInt32(lfileInfo.Length / 1024) / elapsedSec;` part.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187768/can-i-show-file-copy-progress-using-fileinfo-copyto-in-net). In essence, you have to wrap some of the Win32 API calls. The answer from Dennis has some code that should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I’m hardly an expert in this area so I can’t really suggest a full solution but hre are several resources to get you started

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163851.aspx

[Can I show file copy progress using FileInfo.CopyTo() in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187768/can-i-show-file-copy-progress-using-fileinfo-copyto-in-net)