# Copy many files and directories using the system file progress dialog?

Tags: c#, windows, shell, pinvoke, user-experience

I'm looking to copy many files or folders to a different folder, but run it as a utility - ie. my application starting the process as if the user had copied the files into their clipboard and then pasted them into the destination.
I've seen answers elsewhere for copying a directory, or a file, but not mixtures of both under that one progress dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687443/how-to-bring-up-the-built-in-file-copy-dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/187842/352101 ?

Comment: @Bolu That's for one file, and does not show the system file transfer UI.

Comment: @dvnrrs I've got that link on my watch, just need to read my way through that blog post. Incredibly involved stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy files or directories, and have the system provided copy progress dialog, then you are looking for either [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) or [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx).

If you wish to support XP then you need to use `SHFileOperation` at least on that platform. At which point you may as well, in my opinion, use `SHFileOperation` on all platforms. On the other hand, if you are prepared to neglect XP, then you should probably use `IFileOperation`.

Both are pretty easy to use from C#. For `SHFileOperation` you can use the p/invoke declarations provided at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shfileoperation). Since this is a very widely used and useful function there is a good chance that the p/invokes provided there are of good quality.

For `IFileOperation` I'm less familiar with the options. This MSDN article looks to be promising: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx

Comment: To the OP, you may want to look in to [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) too, it contains the wrappers for `SHFileOperation` and other windows common dialogs for you.

Comment: Ah! I had no idea that the API code pack contained wrappers for it. Thanks!

Comment: Windows API Code Pack dose not wrappers any of SHFileOperation or IFileOperation ((