# How to quickly move file on network share to subfolder on same network share?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In a C# .NET 7 Core console application if you do `File.Move(@"\\box\stuff\video.mkv", @"\\box\stuff\fun\video.mkv")` it will do a **copy** and then **delete** on that file. But if you open Windows File Explorer and move (cut & paste) the same file it will get moved in an instant. The file I want to move is 20GB, so it's not feasible to the program to copy and delete. How can do move the file in C# .NET Core the same way File Explorer does?

The network share device is a samba server so my guess is that File Explorer does a remote move call. I simply want to list the files from the server and then move them to subfolders on the same network share.

EDIT: This is different then using any of the file dialogs from windows. This is strictly a batch process which does not require any user input or feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy many files and directories using the system file progress dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240197/copy-many-files-and-directories-using-the-system-file-progress-dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `File.Move`, you can try using the `Move` method in `FileInfo` class.

```
FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(filetoMovePath); 
fileinfo.MoveTo(destFileName);
```

This is much faster compared to static `File`.

[Check Remarks in this MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0)

Comment: That was easy enough, thanks! :)